# Do Synchronized Methods run on a different thread from the UI thread (Android)?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, synchronized

Posting a question for the first time here. Just started programming and coding my first app.

I have an Application class file that has the method fetchUpdates():

```
public synchronized void fetchUpdates() {
    String[] mURLs = getURLs();
    new DownloadJSONData().execute(mURLs[0], mURLs[1]);
}
```

DownloadJSONData is an `asyncTask` that gets updates from the server and the `onPostExecute` method updates an sqlite database using a JSON array from the server.

Different components (widgets and activities) of the app call this method to get updates from the server to update the database.

The question: Does synchronized method run on a separate thread from the UI thread? If so, there should be no problem in moving the code in the `DownloadJSONData` to the synchronized `fetchUpdates()` method right? And if there is a holdup in connecting to the server or downloading the data from the server, it shouldn't block the UI thread right?

The motive: I'm trying to change the `fetchUpdates()` method to return a boolean indicating whether the database was updated or not. However, as it is now (I think) `fetchUpdates()` method finishes before the `asyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method and, hence, `fetchUpdates()` method cannot indicate whether the call to `DownloadJSONData()` updated the database. I need the app components that call the `fetchUpdates()` method to behave differently if the database was updated after the call.

P.S. Since I'm new to programming simple and detailed explanations would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a question for you. Why aren't you updating your database in the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method? Because the `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI Thread and it might cause a hickup.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll bring about the change. Didn't think about that when I wrote the code. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AsyncTask` means that most of the time the calling method will not know the result right away - unless you call `AsyncTask.get()` but you don't want to do that and loose the asynchronous aspect. 
Let's say that you want to display a message to the user when the database has been updated what you should do is start the `AsyncTask` and let it handle the return status of the database update by overriding the correct method. I would also separate the request to the server and database update in two distinct tasks:

```
    public class CallServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Do your request to the server
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (result == SUCCESS) {
            // Display message to indicate successful request
            new UpdateDatabase().execute(params);
        } else {
            // Display error message or whatever you want to do 
        }
    }
}

public class UpdateDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Update the DB
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (result == SUCCESS) {
            // Display success message or whatever you want to do 
        } else {
            // Display error message or whatever you want to do 
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is that the `AsyncTask` should handle the error/success cases and not its caller.

Comment: I have a service that call `fetchUpdates()` methods at a given interval to check for updates to update the database. Suppose I make a toast when failed to connect to server. The toast would popup even when the app is not in focus at the set intervals. Ideally I want the toast to popup only **once** when the user open the app (the MainActivity.class call `fetchUpdates()` on onCreate).

Comment: Then you could display the status message only when called from you main activity and doing nothing when called from the service by passing a parameter to your AsyncTask. For calling it only when the application is open your could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/2003420

Answer (score 6):

No, a synchronized method runs in the same thread. However, no other thread can execute another synchronized method (of the same object) while it is being executed.